# Maze-like puzzle

Tags: visual, mazes

[image: keyword:ascend]

Rules:

> - Start in the top-left arrow, and exit in the bottom-right arrow  <sub>(do I need this?)</sub>
> - You move one step, but not diagonally.
> - By taking steps, you can either go up in the color range or stay in the range.
> - You are not allowed to go down the color range when taking steps.

That's it.

Comment: Could you not have used numbers or something? I don't know about other people, but it's very difficult to tell apart some of these shades.

Comment: @Deusovi I'll try next time, but it's what my mind thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

> [image: solution]
>
>  (note that near the bottom right corner, you have one other option, by taking the last step down one step earlier)